Testability when API contract is fixed
Recently, I spoke to an Engineering Manager about some work I've done:

I had to implement a micro-service to a third party API contract (that they will call). Part of the requirement is to immediately acknowledge the HTTP request, and then do stuff and call a callback endpoint via OAuth. The callback (and OAuth) endpoint(s) are configured in the Java Spring config - we don't receive it at runtime. This API will be published in an internal API platform through which it will be called by the third party.

The Engineering Manager said the following was not best practice:

For automated testing, to avoid having 'test' deployments vs non-test deployments, I added an optional parameter (callbackConfig) that can be used to override the callback (+ OAuth) endpoints. This way, I can redirect the callback to a mock server and retrieve the results to assert on. This parameter is secured by a special role not accessible via the API platform - only accessible from the development environment and automated tests.

Example code:
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyController {

    private final MyService myService;

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('TEST') or #myRequest.callbackConfig() == null && hasRole('STANDARD')")
    @PostMapping
    public void processRequest(@RequestBody final Request myRequest) {
        // Request is a Java Record. CallbackConfig is a POJO. This call here is pseudocode for clarity
        myService.useConfig(myRequest.callbackConfig())

        myService.process(myRequest);
    }
}

What would be the best practice alternative to this?

To be honest, my first reaction was allowing clients to override the OAuth endpoints exposes a security vulnerability... unless I'm misunderstanding the purpose of callbackConfig().

If this "callback config" code is deployed to a production environment, what will stop a malicious client from supplying their own OAuth endpoints as part of a spear phishing campaign. I have all kinds of warning sirens going off right now. This is like asking "is it a good practice to create a backdoor security vulnerability in my application to facilitate automated testing?"

I'm not sure, but you seem to have missed the entire 2nd half of the 2nd paragraph: "This parameter is secured by a special [basic auth] role not accessible via the API platform - only accessible from the development environment and automated tests." Are you saying it's still a vulnerability with this?

There is still a risk. If that token gets compromised then your system is wide open to attack — and your users too. They could be tricked into providing their credentials if an attacker sets up a malicious OAuth site. I've created login systems for automated testing purposes, but you need to be really careful with this. The solution proposed in the question is risky, in my opinion.

@GregBurghardt So this question is asking for better alternatives that fulfil the requirements. Please do share if you can suggest any.

There is no such thing as a "best practice" when it comes to software design. However, your design does appear to be unnecessarily complex.
The biggest problem that I have is that, based on what I see here, callbackConfig() exists only for testability. In other words, you have written and will deliver code as part of your build that is only for testing. I consider this a poor practice, and there are often (but not always) better alternatives).
It's unclear from your description why you cannot use a mocking framework to mock calls in a test environment. If you wanted a broader test, you could write a mock server that listens to requests and responds to various types, with responses ranging from valid responses to error states for the server, and your application configuration would provide a way to specify the URL and port for this server application.

There is no way in the API contract to receive the callback endpoint, making it an app config property. But when the app is deployed, if I want to test (manually or auto) I need to override that config in order to receive the data.

Additionally, we use a mock server in non-prod, but even there the standard callback endpoints are to the (nonprod) third party endpoints.

@AhmedTawfik Why would you want to override, or even allow someone to, override a production configuration? This is not typically desired behavior. Plus, why would your callback endpoints in non-production be to third-party endpoints rather than a server your control? These are probably the good practices that the manager was getting at and understanding why you are deviating from them. Perhaps there are good reasons, but I'm not seeing a rationale yet, either.

So third party had to test integration in non-prod e.g. UAT. Also, in prod I needed to do some manual testing to ensure correctness.

@AhmedTawfik If the manager you were talking to has a similar perspective as I do, they would say that there is no reason to do any kind of testing in production for any reason and that all testing should be done in non-production environments. Some of this may be on the third party - why don't they have a non-prod mirror of their service for developing and testing the integrations? The lack of the third-party providing this kind of service could be a reason to do things differently, but I still don't see why you can't intercept and mock the calls in most environments.

So this is some sort of DNS interception?

@AhmedTawfik No. One option is to use a mocking framework (it looks like you're working in Java, so Mockito is one option) to identify and mock the external calls. You can then return something that looks like a response to your application without making any external calls. Another option would be to build a lightweight server that you run in a test environment that has endpoints that mimic those in the third-party application, but return responses and then configure your application to direct requests at this server instead of the third-party's external server.

I've already mentioned that I use a mock server, in the second quote. And I already use Mockito for unit testing.
